# what can I use instead of .loc when i also have NaN values in my table?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to groupby some athletes by their name an get the smallst age from every person and then sort them by their age from the youngest to the oldest, but in my data there are also some Nan values and i get a FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
Is there any option to skip the records with the Nan values?

Here is my code, tab is a table I read form an csv file which i got from my teacher:

```
tabYoungest=tab.sort_values(by='Age')  
tabYoungestgesamt=tabYoungest.loc[tabYoungest.groupby('Name')['Age'].idxmin()]
tabYoungestgesamt.head(20)
```

Comment: probably as simple as adding `.dropna` within the `.loc`: `tabYoungest.groupby('Name')['Age'].idxmin().dropna()`

Comment: you can use `.fillna()` to change those values, if you dont want to lose the info

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your data.

Comment: It seems like to me that all you really need is `tab.groupby('Name').min()`, note also, you could have used `tabYoungest.reindex(tabYoungest.groupby('Name')['Age'].idxmin())` as the warning states, if you didn't want to change your approach.

Comment: .dropna() solved my proplem :) thx @ALollz

Answer (score 2):

IIUC this can be achieved much more easily by using `.sort_values` + `groupby` + `head`. Output will be youngest age per name, sorted from youngest to oldest with all names with missing ages at the end.

#### Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
tab = pd.DataFrame({'Name': list('ABCDEFGHIJ')*100,
                   'Age': np.random.normal(50,5,1000)})
tab.loc[1000] = ['Z', np.NaN]
```

#### Code:

```
tab = tab.sort_values('Age')
tab.groupby('Name').head(1)

     Name        Age
892     C  34.731178
661     B  36.045018
367     H  36.087328
738     I  36.508191
976     G  36.679370
589     J  37.418481
414     E  37.932485
5       F  38.492307
973     D  38.508971
790     A  39.568047
1000    Z        NaN
```

Comment: Or just `tab.groupby('Name').min()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga good point, that works here, followed by a `.sort` on age, as long as `age` is the only information needed. `.head(1)` is more in line with the output of `.loc[...idxmin()]` as it brings the entire row where the age is the minimum.

Comment: You could use `tab.groupby('Name').agg(['idxmin','min'])` in that case, although, I suspect `head` might be more efficient.